# Inequalities and floors.

Tags: inequality

I've been presented with a question that I actually don't understand.

The question is:

Given
$$\lfloor a\rfloor\leq a<\lfloor a\rfloor+1$$
Write an inequality for $\lfloor a\rfloor$

I'm fine with the floor function - that isn't unfamiliar. And while I can read and understand what the inequality is saying above, I don't know what it means to "write an inequality for $\lfloor a\rfloor$". We need to use the inequality we get to show a further expression which is in the form:

[something]$\leq$[something]<[something], so from this I know that the inequality signs don't change in the inequality I must write, but that's all I know!

Does it mean $\lfloor a\rfloor$ has to be in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging

$$a-1<\lfloor a\rfloor\leq a$$

Comment: So when we are asked to write an inequality for $x$, $x$ must be bound by something potentially less than and something potentially greater than $x$ (i.e. $x$ is in the middle)?

Comment: Basically -- yes.  The inequality I wrote puts lower and upper bounds on the floor in terms of its argument.

Comment: floor(a) can be no bigger than a and never less than a-1

Comment: Awesome, thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Eliot: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As @RRL pointed out, you could rearrange it that way. Depending on what you are doing, it might also be useful to note $$0 \leq a-\lfloor a \rfloor < 1$$